# How do I use boost.compute functions in a functor which will be used by Thrust on a GPU?

Tags: c++, boost, gpgpu, thrust, boost-compute

I'm trying to use a special function provided by boost.math in a thrust algorithm.

Basically, I want to do a transformation, like so

```
  thrust::device_vector<double> in(1000);
  thrust::device_vector<double> out(1000);

  thrust::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), myfunctor());
```

where `myfunctor()` is given by

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/ellint_1.hpp>
.
.
.
struct myfunctor {
  __host__ __device__
  double operator()(double k) {
    return boost::math::ellint_1(sqrt(k));
  }
};
```

I keep getting `warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed` right at the line where `ellint_1` is called in the functor.

Am I doing something wrong or is boost.math not suited for GPGPU use (because from what I've read, i definitely thought it was)?

Comment: I can't test or check it right now but maybe the problem is `sqrt`.

Comment: Boost.compute is a helper for [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). An [example](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/example/simple_kernel.cpp) When the NVIDEA Thrust is similar helper but for [CUDA API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA). And [boost::math](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/math/doc/html/index.html) - is a CPU library.

Comment: So, I was using a CPU library in my device code. Not sure how I missed that. I just did a search for such special functions available for device code, but I can't seem to find anything. Would you happen to know of anything?

Comment: It seems like you would need to implement Legendre Complete Elliptic Integral of first kind by the OpenCL or CUDA kernel. Or find an existing GPGPU implementation, and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Any function called inside `__device__` qualified functions must also be a `__device__` qualified function. And `boost::math::ellint_1()` does not have such qualifier.

See CUDA Programming Guide B.1. - Function Execution Space Specifiers
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-declaration-specifiers

And boost::math is unrelated to boost::compute, with the latter focusing on generic STL-like algorithms and containers.